# Ruby TCPSocket through Proxy

Tags: ruby, sockets, proxy, sidekiq, socks

I have a Socket client (`Socket.tcp`) that I'd like to proxy through another machine. I've blooked in to SOCKS libraries (https://github.com/samuelkadolph/ruby-proxifier), but it seems to require having an active proxy on the machine the code is running, which would proxy ALL network traffic on the machine?

Ideally, this will be a Sidekiq background job where just the worker's code is proxied, not the other code on the server (it will be within a Rails application).

I see the Net::SSH library (https://net-ssh.github.io/ssh/v2/api/classes/Net/SSH/Proxy/SOCKS5.html) has some stuff around SOCKS, but I'm unsure if this is the best approach (does this lib establish the SOCKS proxy?).

Any pointers to proxying an individual socket client would be really helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I do not fully get your setup and requirements. To me it sounds as if I would use port forwarding/tunneling via ssh. Like for what exactly do you need the client, the proxy and the endpoint?

Comment: Sorry for the vagueness. After some more research, I think tunneling via SSH does make sense. I think many of the questions in my head are around whether it's possible to do this all at the software layer, rather than rely on the fact that a SOCKS proxy is already established on the application server. This will be spreading network activity over potentially hundreds of proxies and need to consider performance. I guess the better performing would be having those tunnels already established and then pointing to the appropriate one in code?

Comment: It didnt help :) I do not understand your setup and requirement more than before :) . Gut feeling says: build some tunnels beforehand, forget socks (although btw kind-of-socks is built-in in openssh (`ssh -D`, which is awesome for simplest proxying when using a public internet access). You could also go with autossh and the likes but like you said I would just make sure all the tunnels are up beforehand. The question then might go to serverfault.com .

Comment: And you want to make sure that the keys you use to build the tunnels can do nothing more but port forwarding.

Comment: Yup, I was thinking about using `ssh -D`, so glad you mentioned it. Thanks again for the thoughts, it was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up going with a `ssh -D` tunnel on the application server and keeping a reference to the proxy in application and patching the network library to use https://github.com/samuelkadolph/ruby-proxifier.